# Scripting for table data in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following data file, EMP.txt:

```
SNO,NAME,GENDER,COMPANY,EMPID,SALARY,JOINING_DATE,PHONE_NO,LOCATION
1,sravan kumar,M,ibm,1095,20000,01-SEP-2014,7651523,HYDERABAD
2,Vijay Prakash,M,IBM,2056,30000,05-JAN-2014,9936789,HYDERABAD
3,Surya,M,HP,1046,30000,01-FEB-2013,8904561,BANGALORE
4,Karthik,M,APPLE,1023,10000,03-JUN-2014,756098,HYDERABAD
5,Latha,F,MAPR,1010,20000,05-FEB-2012,9874522,BANGALORE
6,Swetha,F,MAPR,1080,30000,04-JUN-2014,98701234,HYDERABAD
7,Sunil,M,GOOGLE,1098,34000,07-SEP-2014,993451,BANGALORE
```

the above data is stored in file EMP.txt

I Want script to list emp_name,Emp_id,Salary,location whose salary is greater than 20000.
plz help me

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you, but if you have specific questions about a particular step of the problem, we'd be happy to help.

Comment: You need to do your own homework.

Comment: i did it using for loop cat command and lot more but iam still facing problem to get the script

Comment: i just want solution only for the first question remaining question i can do it sir DavidPostill

Answer (score 0):

AS it is my work i tried to get the output Thank you @DavidPostill you made me to try by self

for var in `cat EMP.txt | tail –n  +2`                                                                                     #tail -n +2 if for removing the header

do

sal=`echo $var | cut -d "," -f6`#for seleceting salary field

if [ $sal -gt 20000 ]

then

echo $var          #displaying each line from $var
fi

done